# How to abort a looping AJAX request to MVC controller (Editing due to no appropriate response)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I want to send file chunks to server async to server (MVC action in a controller). I want to ensure that requests that I am sending through JS can be cancelled midway. I know about AJAX abort() but I think since the requests are async I am having little option other than setting a Session variable on MVC controller which rejects all blocks coming to it after being set. Please tell me the optimal way to do this. Can you tell me whether abort() can be used in this scenario and if yes then how? What are the other strategies I can follow to make this better?

My JS method is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    context: this,
    async: true,
    url: "/Home/PrepareMetaData",
    data: { "blocksCount": totalNumberOfBlocks, "fileName": file.name, "fileSize": file.size },
    dataType: "json",
    error: function () {
        statusLabel.innerHTML = 'Failed to send file meta data. Retry after some time.';
        progressElement.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
    },
    success: function () {
        var start = 0;
        var end = Math.min(blockLength, file.size) - 1;
        var incrimentalIdentifier = 1;
        while (start <= file.size - 1 && !window.haltExecution) {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append(incrimentalIdentifier, file.webkitSlice(start, end));
            xhr = $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: '/Home/UploadBlock',
                context: this,
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                error: function (notice) {
                    statusLabel.innerHTML = notice;
                    progressElement.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
                    haltExecution = true;
                },
                success: function (notice) {
                    blockCounter += 1;
                    if (notice.error || notice.isLastBlock) {
                        this.message = notice.message;
                    }

                    if (notice.error || blockCounter == totalNumberOfBlocks) {
                        statusLabel.innerHTML = this.message;
                        progressElement.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
                        haltExecution = true;
                    }
                }
            });

            start = end + 1;
            end = Math.min(start + blockLength, file.size) - 1;
            incrimentalIdentifier++;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Edit:
I agree with the comments but if I make the Ajax request synchronous then I would be going against the nature of Ajax and would also be risk performance degrade. Another issue would be stuck UI. Even if I use Web Worker for this it would make my code async as it is now. What are your views??

Comment: you cannot cancel the ajax request midway once the request is made it cannot be cancelled

Comment: @3nigma is correct. The request is an HTTP transaction, and once the packets are out on the wire it's just not possible to get them back.

Comment: @Pointy You are both wrong. Ajax requests CAN be aborted. The packets aren't all sent immediately, it takes a little while to upload a file. Read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort-method

Comment: @david you can abort the process in the client, sure, but you can't guarantee that the server didn't get the HTTP request and start reacting to it, and you can't make the server abort its handling (unless you've got your own protocol to do that, which'd require sending another request of some sort).

Comment: @Pointy What? We're not talking about UPD datagrams here. If the client aborts the connection the server will know about it.

Comment: Well in the case of a file upload that's probably true, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rewrite which should point you in the right direction. You need to send each subsequent chunk in the success handler of the previous one, rather than sending them all at once. This is just a quick hack around what you already had so it's not perfect, but it should help.

```
var sendFile = function(){
    var start = 0;
    var end = Math.min(blockLength, file.size) - 1;
    var incrimentalIdentifier = 1;
    // I assume the following variables are in scope already:
    // file, blockCounter, haltExecution
    var sendNextChunk = function(){
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append(incrimentalIdentifier, file.webkitSlice(start, end));
        xhr = $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: '/Home/UploadBlock',
            context: this,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            error: function (notice) {
                statusLabel.innerHTML = notice;
                progressElement.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
                haltExecution = true;
            },
            success: function (notice) {
                blockCounter += 1;
                if (notice.error || notice.isLastBlock) {
                    this.message = notice.message;
                }

                if (notice.error || blockCounter == totalNumberOfBlocks) {
                    statusLabel.innerHTML = this.message;
                    progressElement.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
                    haltExecution = true;
                    return; // We are finished sending I assume?
                }

                start = end + 1;
                end = Math.min(start + blockLength, file.size) - 1;
                incrimentalIdentifier++;

                // Send the next block.
                sendNextChunk();
            }
        });
    };

    //Start sending:
    sendNextChunk();
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    context: this,
    async: true,
    url: "/Home/PrepareMetaData",
    data: { "blocksCount": totalNumberOfBlocks, "fileName": file.name, "fileSize": file.size },
    dataType: "json",
    error: function () {
        statusLabel.innerHTML = 'Failed to send file meta data. Retry after some time.';
        progressElement.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
    },
    success: sendFile
});
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Thanks for your help David. You have hit the bulls eye.

Answer (score 0):

if you use async option you can't run any js until the req is completed (with error or not) so the only solution is to cancel from server side or don't use async.

Comment: Yes I do concur with you, but this is not the optimal solution of the issue. Do you know of a more optimal approach to the issue?

Comment: I think you have it the wrong way around @cuzzea, with async enabled you CAN keep running JS.